# Can QGIS save layer direct to PostGIS?

Tags: qgis, postgis

I see that there is no option in the layer->save as menu for saving to a postgis database.  There are for both SpatiaLite and SQLite.

I am guessing that the interface to PostGIS is significantly more complex than either of the "Lite" options and it has simply never made it to the top of anyone's todo list seeing as there are reasonably straight forward workarounds that can (presumably ?) be automated by scripting.

I ask because I am looking for something relatively straight forward to work on as a programming project involving QGIS. I am assuming that I can use the other two as a sort of template along with the shape to Postgres plugin.  I am an experienced programmer but a relative novice at GIS stuff.

Comment: +1 Your original title could only be answered by someone from the QGIS development team so I changed it to one open to more potential answers, yet still likely to uncover the information that you seek.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DB Manager can import QGIS layer data directly into PostGIS. DB Manager even supports drag and drop. It's different from "save as" but not really more difficult.

[image]

Comment: Answers the revised question and probably explains why there isn't a specific tool.  Thanks!